# How to Deploy/compile multiple Stored Procedures using IBM Data Studio?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-data-studio

I am using IBM data studio  4.1.2 client to connect to DB2 data base. I want to know how to deploy(compile) multiple Stored procedures(SP) at once. It was very straight forward and easy in Toad. But unfortunately I cannot use Toad because of some company policy of mine.

In Data Studio I tried these 1) Data source explorer -> Schema -> Stored procedure -> right click -> new stored procedure -> wrote two simple SP one after the other. 'END' of first SP asked 'Statement terminator expected', When I put ';' after END then 'Statement terminator expected instead of ;', when I used '--' at the top then all statements including BEGIN statement of second SP giving syntax error 'END was expected to form a complete scope'. I tried all possible workarounds, But still same syntax error.

I am 100 % sure that there is nothing wrong in SP. But I don't know what is the solution for this. I had gone through lot many IBM support pages, tutorials, demo. All of them demonstrates how to compile one SP at a time opening separate editor window. Actually I have to deploy 300 odd SPs. Please Help me.

This question is not a duplicate of other as This is related to Multiple SP deployment using IDE.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766241/error-while-creating-procedure-in-db2/28767867#28767867

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compund statement in db2 command line processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855088/compund-statement-in-db2-command-line-processor)

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for your suggestions, But still Not able to get relevant answer for my question. This question is on 'Multiple' SP compilation using 'IBM data studio' editor. Your suggestions answer how to compile 'a' Stored procedure from 'Command prompt interface'

Comment: My suggestion is about properly setting the statement terminator. `CREATE PROCEDURE` is a statement.